# Newline command does not work in latex formula in Libre Office

Tags: ubuntu, latex, libreoffice-writer, newlines

I am using Libre Office Writer 4.2.8.2 in Ubuntu 14.04.

When I select Insert->Object->Formula and write some formula like `<some formula> newline <some formula>` it renders as `<some formula> ? <some formula>` (question mark is inverted upside down) while I want linebreak.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you are writing something like:
3 + newline
4 = 7.
The "+" operator expects two operands.  The equation editor expects newlines to be placed after an operator which expects two operands.  Try this:
3 + 4 = 7 "and"
4 - 3 = 1.

Comment: Pardon my error.  Try this: 3 + 4 = 7 "and" newline 4 - 3 = 1.

Comment: Please edit this into your answer.

Comment: Yes, this is my case. But can I still deliberately `newline` after `+`?